# C++ Print array list in order?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have been assigned a task on c++, and I've almost finished it, but I got stuck on the last
"bonus" task, which is:

Modify the program so that it outputs a list in order of number of pancakes eaten of all 10 people.
i.e.
Person 4: ate 10 pancakes

Person 3: ate 7 pancakes

Person 8: ate 4 pancakes

...

Person 5: ate 0 pancakes

Pay attention that the person's number should match correctly to the number of pancakes he ate!

The code I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int temp=0;
int temp2=0;
int minimum,location=1;
int pan[10] = {};
for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
{
    cout << "How many pancakes did person " << i << " eat? ";
    cin >> pan[i];
}
for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
{
    if(pan[i]>temp)
    {
        temp=pan[i];
        temp2=i;
    }
}
minimum = pan[0];
for(int i=1;i<11;i++)
{
    if(pan[i] < minimum)
    {
        minimum = pan[i];
        location=i;
    }
}
cout << "The person who ate the most pancakes is person " << temp2 << endl;
cout << "The person who ate the least pancakes is person " << location << endl;
return 0;


}
```

So, how can I print the correct order according to the amount of pancakes eaten AND the person's number? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:I am only allowed to use:

variables, data types, and numerical operators

basic input/output

logic (if statements, switch statements)

loops (for, while, do-while)

arrays

Comment: Make a struct Person that contains the number and pancakes. Sort according to pancakes and output.

Comment: I am only allowed to use the following:

variables, data types, and numerical operators

basic input/output

logic (if statements, switch statements)

loops (for, while, do-while)

arrays

Comment: How many items do your for-loops visit? How large is your pan array?

Comment: int pan[10] = {}; So the size is 10.

Comment: Output i in your loops to see what you are accessing.

Comment: A struct is a datatype in my world. If you can't use structs, you have to emulate that.

Comment: Well, I still can't use structs.

Comment: Please state your requirements in the question.

Comment: By the way, you have a very big problem in your code, you write out of bounds in the `pan` array, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Remember that the last valid index of an array is the size minus one, in your case `10 - 1`. You use indexes up to `10`.

Comment: As for your problem, I suggest you [read more about sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), because you only do a very partial sorting.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll use it.Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) with the person as the key, and the number of pancakes as data, and have a custom comparator function that compares the number of pancakes.

Then printing in order will be as simple as iterating from the beginning to the end.

Comment: As I said, the only things I can use are:
variables, data types, and numerical operators
basic input/output
logic (if statements, switch statements)
loops (for, while, do-while)
arrays
I can't use fancy things, that's the limitation.

Comment: @user3402353 Well, `std::map` *is* a data type. Do you mean *basic* data types (like e.g. `int`)?

Comment: Yes, basic data types since that makes the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about sorting algorithms, reading the restriction of the task let me believe that this is the goal of the bonus. The more easy sorting algorithms are:

1-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort
2-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Reading the code, your are calculating min and max of the pancake eaten persons. When implementing sorting this two could be easily found as first and last person in the array

I would recommend saving person index and pancake eaten count (ex: with std::pair) if not allowed to use pair (could make and struct by yourself)

`struct pair {
     long first;
     long second;
};`

This is needed for maintaining info of person index when sorting the array by pancake eaten count.

Some example code:

```
std::vector<std::pair<long, long>> pan(10);

for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
{
    cout << "How many pancakes did person " << i << " eat? ";
    cin >> pan[i].second;
    pan[i].first = i;
}

// sort using bubble or insertion sort

cout << "The person who ate the most pancakes is person " << pan.back().first << endl;
cout << "The person who ate the least pancakes is person " << pan.front().first << endl;

// Print persons in order.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your for loops are not valid.

`for(int i=0;i<11;i++)

Your table size is 10 (valid indexes: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 without 10!) `

These all loops can be replaced with use for example `vector` and a few `stl` functions:

```
vector<int> personsPancakes = {3, 7, 2, 8, 4};

auto maxIt = max_element(begin(personsPancakes), end(personsPancakes)); // iterator to max element
auto minIt = min_element(begin(personsPancakes), end(personsPancakes)); // iterator to min element

cout << "Max value index: " << distance(begin(personsPancakes), maxIt) << " Value: " << *maxIt << endl;
cout << "Min value index: " << distance(begin(personsPancakes), minIt) << " Value: " << *minIt << endl;
```

Output:

```
Max value index: 3 Value: 8
Min value index: 2 Value: 2
```